# Cross-talk filter with known source

Tags: signal-processing

Hello fellow Stackers,

This question was also posted on StackOverflow, but perhaps this is a more suitable location for this question. I currently work in an experimental rock mechanics lab, and when I conduct an experiment, I record the output signals such as effective torque, normal force and motor velocity. However, the latter quantity causes significant cross-talk over the recorded channels, and I want to filter this out. Let me give an example:
[image]
Here the upper plot is the strong signal (motor velocity), and the lower is an idle signal that is affected by the cross-talk (blue is raw signal, red is median filtered). The idle channel is only recording noise. We see three effects here. When the motor voltage changes:

1. the amplitude of the noise increases
2. the idle signal's median shifts
3. there is a spike that lasts approximately 0.1 seconds

If we zoom in on the first spike that occurs at around 115 seconds, we get the following plot. This does not seem to be your typical delta-function type of spike, but rather some kind of electronic "echo".
[image]

I have seen much work on blind source separation through independent component analysis (ICA), but that did not prove to be effective in my situation. However, since I know the shape of the signal that is causing the cross-talk, there may be better ways to include this information. My question is this: is there a filter or a combination of filters that can tackle the effects mentioned above?

As I am a geologist and not an electrician or mathematician, I don't have a proper background for this kind of material, so please bear with me. I write Python, MATLAB and C++ quite well, so suggested algorithms written in any of those languages is preferred (but not required).

Thanks

Comment: Since you are not getting help here, I'd suggest you try dsp.stackexchange.com